# Implementing HEAD and GET requests, simple web server in C

Tags: c, linux, httpserver

I'm making a simple web server in C, and I need to handle both simple and full versions of http 1.0 methods HEAD and GET requests. All other requests should result in status code 501. It's my first time programming a web server and finding what you need is kind of hard. Can someone help me get on the right track here. How do I handle the requests? 
My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 512




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int portnumber;
    int sockfd; //for new client connections
    int sockfd_current; //for accepted clients
    struct sockaddr_in sockIn;
    struct sockaddr_in portIn;
    char buffert[SIZE];
    int addrlen;
    char ipAddress[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; //incomming IP-address to server with length


    portnumber= atoi(argv[1]);  //second parameter passed from main into portnumber


    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)  //trying to create socket address-family
    {   
        perror ("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&sockIn, 0, sizeof(sockIn)); //assign memory and set socket address structure
    sockIn.sin_family= AF_INET;
    sockIn.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY;
    sockIn.sin_port = htons(portnumber); //assign port to network byteorder: hostToNetwork

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockIn, sizeof(sockIn)) == -1)//trying to assign address to socket
    {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == -1)    //trying to Listen for clients that fulfills the requirements  
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    addrlen = sizeof(portIn);
    if((sockfd_current = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &portIn, (socklen_t*) &addrlen)) == -1)  //trying to Create a new socket for the accepted client
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }

//Start communication aka HEAD/GET from client...
    printf("Accepting connection...\n\n");
    if(recv(sockfd_current, buffert, sizeof(buffert), 0) == -1) //trying to recive message from client
    {
        perror("Failed to recive request from client");
        exit(1);
    }

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &portIn.sin_addr, ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress)); //convert binary-ip from client to "networkToPresentable" string
    printf("Request from %s:%i\n", ipAddress, ntohs(portIn.sin_port));
    printf("Message: %s\n", buffert);


//Responds to clients request
    printf("Send Response:\n\n");
    fgets(buffert, SIZE - 1, stdin);

    if(send(sockfd_current, buffert, strlen(buffert) + 1, 0) == -1) 
    {
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }


    close(sockfd_current);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The assignment i got was to only make the server and not the client, so I should only have to handle the requests.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: My question is how to implement the responds from the server, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Er. You do that by writing code that handles the requests. ???

Comment: As I said, I'm quite new to this, so could you help me figure out what to do? How do I handle the request?

Comment: How were you able to get this far and not be able to handle the request?

Comment: In practice **HTTP is a** quite **complex protocol** and you could spend more than a year of work to implement it. Better use (or at least study the source code of) some free software HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/). In other words, coding an HTTP compliant web server (which *cannot be simple*, if you care about the corner cases of HTTP) is never easy, and the evil is in the details.

Comment: The thing is it's hard to understand what I have actually done and what I need to do. So I kind of just tried everything I found and kept what made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTTP protocol, since the first "word" is the method, you have to check that first.

Use standard functions like `strchr()` or `strtok()` to split the buffer into "words". Then use something like `strcmp()` to see if the "word" is "GET" or "HEAD".

Once you got that, write three cases. If the word is "GET", you send the requested resource, and for "HEAD", you send just the HEAD. If the first "word" is anything else, you'll send the appropriate "Not Implemented" response.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll do that.